# Is the induced map in the following diagram a regular epimorphism?

Tags: category-theory, diagram-chasing

Consider the following commutative diagram in a semiabelian category
[image]

where $f,f',\alpha$ and $\beta$ are regular epimorphisms. Is it true that the induced dotted map is a regular epimorphism too? If so, how can I prove it?
If not, is the previous statement true when we add the hypothesis that the right-hand square is a pushout?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily true that the induced map will always be a regular epi. In fact, in a semi-abelian category this map being a regular epimorphism is equivalent to the square being a pushout.

Indeed, if the square is a pushout, then the canonical arrow $( \alpha,f) :A\to A'\times_{B'}B$ given by the universal property of the pullback is a regular epimorphism (and the converse is true as well); this is a consequence Theorem 5.2 in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00872942) and the fact that every semi-abelian category is exact and Mal'tsev. Then you have a diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD} Ker(f) @>{\ker(f)}>> A @>{f}>> B 
\\  @V{\gamma_1}VV @V{(\alpha,f)}VV @VV{1_B}V \\
 Ker(\psi_2) @>{\ker(\psi_2)}>> A'\times_{B'}B @>{\psi_2}>> B
\\ @V{\gamma_2}VV @V{\psi_1}VV @VV{\beta}V
\\  Ker(f') @>>{\ker(f')}> A' @>>{f'}> B'.
\end{CD}
Now the bottom right square is pullback by definition, hence the induced map $\gamma_2$ is an isomorphism, and the map $1_B$ is a monomorphism, hence the top left square is a pullback (these two properties hold in any pointed category). In particular, since regular epimorphisms are stable, $\gamma_1$ is a regular epimorphism, and thus so is the composition $\gamma_2\gamma_1$. This is exactly your dotted arrow.

Comment: The problem is that I don't see how to show the equivalence between the right-hand square being a pushout and the map $(\alpha,f)$ being regular epimorphism

Comment: @I'mD. It's definitely non-trivial. I've added a reference, sorry for not doing this earlier.

Comment: Thanks! A further (and probably trivial) question: is at least the induced map always epi (even without the right-hand square being a pushout)? If not, is there an easy condition to ask in order to obtain that?

Comment: @I'mD. The induced map being an epi is already enough to prove that the right-hand square is a pushout. So in fact, it is an epi if and only if it is a regular epi!